# execute terraform inside loop on bash script

Tags: shell, terraform

Im trying to execute a command, and when I run it inside a shell loop is not working but does if I do it outside the loop

I want to get some outputs from a terraform output command getting one element on each iteration.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 0 1 2
do
   'terraform output -json nodes | jq '.value[$i]''
done

terraform output
terraform output -json nodes | jq '.value[1]'
```

The output is being:

```
./run.sh: line 5: terraform output -json nodes | jq '.value[0]': command not found
./run.sh: line 5: terraform output -json nodes | jq '.value[1]': command not found
./run.sh: line 5: terraform output -json nodes | jq '.value[2]': command not found
nodes = [
    node01,
    node02,
    node03
]
"node02"
```

And I expected:

```
"node01"
"node02"
"node03"
nodes = [
    node01,
    node02,
    node03
]
"node02"
```

Comment: can you share a single object of  nodes

Comment: Remove the leading and trailing single-quotes. Also `$i` will not expand inside single quotes, use double quotes to expand it.

Comment: Thanks! @KamilCuk I tried with " "  and getting the output on a variable first and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Following @KamilCuk advice I tried with double quotes and I split the command on two parts also, so It looks like this now and It is working:

```
nodes=$(terraform output -json nodes)
nodes_config_ip=$(terraform output -json nodes_iface_1_ips)
aws_region=$(terraform output aws_region)

for i in $(seq 0 $(($n_nodes-1)))
do
  node=$(echo $nodes | jq ".value[$i]")
  node_config_ip=$(echo $nodes_config_ip | jq ".value[$i]")
  echo $node $node_config_ip
done
```